# IdentityServer3 - Extending Claims/Roles - Adding Attributes to Permissions

Tags: identityserver3

We are in the process of migrating our suite of sales website management tools from standalone to a web interface. Our design has a website owner logging in through our main web portal, then selecting one of our sub-applications to manage things like their basic site content, their inventory, their tracking script tags, etc. I'm researching IdentityServer3 to see if it will work as our SSO solution.

The tricky part is that each application needs to know which website a given user has permissions for after they log in. The user might have Administrator permission on websites 1 and 2, but only View permission on website 3. Is there a way to extend Claims to say that a user has a certain Role for a certain website? Even just adding an "id" attribute to a Role/Claim would be good enough. It's not feasible for us to create separate roles for each website (we're going to launch with a couple hundred), unless there's a way to avoid having to authorize them all individually in the clients. Maybe there's a way to structure the Role names and use a custom ResourceAuthorizationManager to parse out the info we need? We'd also have to be able to pass this information around the sub-applications with the other Identity information, but as part of the specific Roles the user has in their Claims, so that the clients have access to which websites a user has permissions for.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer - as the name implies - is about identity - not permissions.

The job of identityserver is to provide a stable and consistent identity to one or more applications.

Everything application specific (like permissions) should be handled in the application itself.

You could e.g. create a separate permission service (secured by identityserver) that allows your applications to retrieve the permission of the user **in the context of the application** and feed that into the authorization logic.

Comment: But IdentityServer does know about Roles. Are you saying that those roles and their use with the Authorize attribute doesn't match what IdentityServer is designed for?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to extend the Identity payload that gets passed around between the IDsrv and hte Clients so that it has the information I want inside it.

Comment: You have full control over which claims go into which token - that's what scopes are for. The documentation has all the details. My general advice still stands.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity, it has a table AspNetUserClaims, can I add the user permission related claims to this table from application (using some api) ? Please share your thoughts.